# Unpivot columns of cube for SSRS report

Tags: reporting-services, mdx, ssrs-2012

I need to modify a report that has a ton of fields to pivot some columns. It  uses a SSAS cube.  I don't know MDX and learning it for this task isn't really feasible.

Example: Existing

```
Date    Amount    SalesPerson1  Salesperson2 Manager 1  Product nbr
4/1/15  100       JSMtih        JDoe        TPrice     99
```

New Results

```
Participant  Participant Role  Date    Amount Product Nbr
JSmith       SalesPerson1      4/1/15    100  99
JDOE         Salesperson2      4/1/15    100  99
TPRice       Manager1          4/1/15    100  99
```

I could rewrite the report using SQL and do an UNPIVOT (I did write the query), but to reconstruct the report would be a ton of work (it has around 10 cascading parameters, sections that collapse/expand, etc.)

Is modifying the MDX to unpivot some columns easy?  I couldn't find an unpivot for MDX and I am guessing it is just inherent in MDX.

MDX Code:

```
 SELECT 
    NONEMPTY({ 
        [Measures].[Outstanding Balance], 
        [Measures].[TM Fee], 
        [Measures].[Upfront Fee], 
        [Measures].[Non Recurring Fee], 
        [Measures].[Recurring Fee], 
        [Measures].[Syndication Fee], 
        [Measures].[Recap Fee], 
        [Measures].[International Fee], 
        [Measures].[Total Deposits Expected], 
        [Measures].[ACE], 
        [Measures].[Commitments], 
        [Measures].[Swap Fee], 
        [Measures].[Global Commitment], 
        [Measures].[Loan Fundings Expected One], 
        [Measures].[Loan Fundings Expected Two], 
        [Measures].[Change Amount], 
        [Measures].[Total Fees], 
        [Measures].[Private Balance] 
        }) ON COLUMNS, 
    NONEMPTY ({(
        [Account].[Account Number].[Account Number].ALLMEMBERS * 
        [Account].[Non Accrual Flag].[Non Accrual Flag].ALLMEMBERS * 
        [Deal].[Deal ID].[Deal ID].ALLMEMBERS * 
        [Deal].[Hierarchy Type].[Hierarchy Type].ALLMEMBERS * 
        [Deal].[Officer One].[Officer One].ALLMEMBERS * 
        [Deal].[Officer Two].[Officer Two].ALLMEMBERS * 
        [Deal].[Other Competing Banks].[Other Competing Banks].ALLMEMBERS * 
        [Deal].[Winning Bank].[Winning Bank].ALLMEMBERS * 
        [Deal].[Officer Three].[Officer Three].ALLMEMBERS * 
        [Deal].[Group].[Group].ALLMEMBERS * 
        [Deal].[Competitor One].[Competitor One].ALLMEMBERS * 
        [Deal].[Incumbentbank].[Incumbentbank].ALLMEMBERS * 
        [Deal].[Competitor Two].[Competitor Two].ALLMEMBERS * 
        [Deal].[New Target Market].[New Target Market].ALLMEMBERS * 
        [Deal].[Approval Description].[Approval Description].ALLMEMBERS * 
        [Deal].[Loan Disposition].[Loan Disposition].ALLMEMBERS * 
        [Deal].[Process Center].[Process Center].ALLMEMBERS * 
        [Deal].[Process Job].[Process Job].ALLMEMBERS * 
        [Deal].[Deal Type].[Deal Type].ALLMEMBERS * 
        [Deal].[Screener].[Screener].ALLMEMBERS * 
        [Deal].[Part Or Synd].[Part Or Synd].ALLMEMBERS * 
        [Deal].[Department].[Department].ALLMEMBERS * 
[Deal].[Party Package Id].[Party Package Id].ALLMEMBERS *
        [Deal].[Stage].[Stage].ALLMEMBERS * 
        [Deal].[Stage Date].[Stage Date].ALLMEMBERS * 
        [Deal].[Referral].[Referral].ALLMEMBERS * 
        [Deal].[Deal NAICS Code].[Deal NAICS Code].ALLMEMBERS * 
        [Deal].[Document Type].[Document Type].ALLMEMBERS * 
        [Deal].[Internal Referral].[Internal Referral].ALLMEMBERS * 
        [Deal].[External Referral].[External Referral].ALLMEMBERS * 
        [Deal].[Referral Category].[Referral Category].ALLMEMBERS * 
        [Deal].[Underwriter].[Underwriter].ALLMEMBERS * 
        [Deal].[Product Partner1].[Product Partner1].ALLMEMBERS * 
        [Deal].[Product Partner2].[Product Partner2].ALLMEMBERS * 
        [Deal].[Manager1].[Manager1].ALLMEMBERS * 
        [Deal].[Manager2].[Manager2].ALLMEMBERS * 
        [Deal].[Other Participant].[Other Participant].ALLMEMBERS * 
        [Deal].[Agent].[Agent].ALLMEMBERS * 
        [Deal].[Deal Source].[Deal Source].ALLMEMBERS * 
        [Deal].[Target Market Client].[Target Market Client].ALLMEMBERS * 
        [Deal].[Reason].[Reason].ALLMEMBERS * 
        [Deal].[Client Status As Of Deal Input].[Client Status As Of Deal Input].ALLMEMBERS * 
        [Deal].[Source System].[Source System].ALLMEMBERS * 
        [Deal].[Stage ID].[Stage ID].ALLMEMBERS * 
        [Deal].[ABLBDO].[ABLBDO]. ALLMEMBERS *
        [Party].[Customer Number].[Customer Number].ALLMEMBERS * 
        [Party].[Party NAICS Code].[Party NAICS Code].ALLMEMBERS * 
        [Party].[Party Name].[Party Name].ALLMEMBERS * 
        [Party].[Name].[Name].ALLMEMBERS * 
        [Product].[Product Type Number].[Product Type Number].ALLMEMBERS * 
        [Product].[CB Description].[CB Description].ALLMEMBERS * 
        [Service Transaction].[Service Transaction Key].[Service Transaction Key].ALLMEMBERS *      
        [Service Transaction].[Expected Funding Date Two].[Expected Funding Date Two].ALLMEMBERS * 
        [Service Transaction].[Expected Funding Date One].[Expected Funding Date One].ALLMEMBERS * 
        [Service Transaction].[Gross Revenue Date].[Gross Revenue Date].ALLMEMBERS * 
        [Service Transaction].[Loan Action].[Loan Action].ALLMEMBERS * 
        [Service Transaction].[Queue Creation Date].[Queue Creation Date].ALLMEMBERS * 
        [Service Transaction].[Loan Open Date].[Loan Open Date].ALLMEMBERS * 
        [Service Transaction].[Comments].[Comments].ALLMEMBERS * 
        [Service Transaction].[Next Maturity Date].[Next Maturity Date].ALLMEMBERS * 
        [Service Transaction].[Creation Date].[Creation Date].ALLMEMBERS * 
        [Service Transaction].[Total Loan Fundings Expected].[Total Loan Fundings Expected].ALLMEMBERS * 
        [Service Transaction].[Risk Rating].[Risk Rating].ALLMEMBERS * 
        [Service Transaction].[Last Modified On].[Last Modified On].ALLMEMBERS * 
        [Service Transaction].[Revenue].[Revenue].ALLMEMBERS * 
        [Service Transaction].[Note Rate].[Note Rate].ALLMEMBERS * 
        [Service Transaction].[RLOC Stock UDF].[RLOC Stock UDF].ALLMEMBERS * 
        [Service Transaction].[Basis Points].[Basis Points].ALLMEMBERS * 
        [Service Transaction].[Pricing Index].[Pricing Index].ALLMEMBERS * 
        [Service Transaction].[Law Firm].[Law Firm].ALLMEMBERS * 
        [Service Transaction].[Cost Center].[Cost Center].ALLMEMBERS * 
        [Service Transaction].[Expected Funding Date].[Expected Funding Date].ALLMEMBERS * 
        [Service Transaction].[Year].[Year].ALLMEMBERS * 
        [Service Transaction].[Estimated Closing Date].[Estimated Closing Date].ALLMEMBERS * 
        [Service Transaction].[Expected Funding Month].[Expected Funding Month].ALLMEMBERS * 
        [Service Transaction].[Expected Deposit Funding Date].[Expected Deposit Funding Date].ALLMEMBERS * 
        [Pipeline Dates].[Approved Date].[Approved Date].ALLMEMBERS * 
        [Pipeline Dates].[Closed Date].[Closed Date].ALLMEMBERS * 
        [Pipeline Dates].[Declined Date].[Declined Date].ALLMEMBERS * 
        [Pipeline Dates].[Discussion Date].[Discussion Date].ALLMEMBERS * 
        [Pipeline Dates].[Documentation Date].[Documentation Date].ALLMEMBERS * 
        [Pipeline Dates].[Lost Date].[Lost Date].ALLMEMBERS * 
        [Pipeline Dates].[PAR Date].[PAR Date].ALLMEMBERS * 
        [Pipeline Dates].[Proposal Date].[Proposal Date].ALLMEMBERS * 
        [Pipeline Dates].[Suspended Date].[Suspended Date].ALLMEMBERS * 
        [Pipeline Dates].[Term Sheet Date].[Term Sheet Date].ALLMEMBERS * 
        [Pipeline Dates].[Underwriting Date].[Underwriting Date].ALLMEMBERS * 
        [Pipeline Dates].[Withdrawn Date].[Withdrawn Date].ALLMEMBERS 
        )}) DIMENSION PROPERTIES MEMBER_CAPTION, MEMBER_UNIQUE_NAME ON ROWS 
FROM ( 
    SELECT ( STRTOSET(@DealDocumentType, CONSTRAINED) ) ON COLUMNS FROM ( 

      SELECT ( STRTOSET(@DealDealType, CONSTRAINED) ) ON COLUMNS FROM ( 

        SELECT ( STRTOSET(@ProductProductDescription, CONSTRAINED) ) ON COLUMNS FROM ( 
         SELECT ( STRTOSET(@DealNonPrimaryOfficer, CONSTRAINED) ) ON COLUMNS FROM ( 
          SELECT ( STRTOSET(@DealOfficerOne, CONSTRAINED) ) ON COLUMNS FROM ( 
           SELECT ( STRTOSET(@DealClientStatusAsOfDealInput, CONSTRAINED) ) ON COLUMNS FROM ( 
            SELECT ( STRTOSET(@ServiceTransactionCostCenter, CONSTRAINED) ) ON COLUMNS FROM ( 
             SELECT ( STRTOSET(@DealGroup, CONSTRAINED) ) ON COLUMNS FROM ( 
              SELECT ( STRTOSET(@ClosingDateCalendar, CONSTRAINED) ) ON COLUMNS FROM ( 
               SELECT ( STRTOSET(@DealStage, CONSTRAINED) ) ON COLUMNS FROM [Pipeline] 
                )
               )
              )
             )
            )
           )
          )
         )
        )
       )
```

Comment: Can you provide the MDX?

Comment: I added it.  The fields I need to unpivot are Officer 1-3, underwriter, etc. (anything that sounds like a person).

Answer (score 1):

You could use UNION to get a set with all the people in the same column.

But that maybe not produce the same results you want.
You would be getting the "Totals" for Manager1 and Manager2. Give it a try.

```
WITH
SET myPeople
AS
UNION(
[Deal].[Manager1].[Manager1].ALLMEMBERS,
[Deal].[Manager2].[Manager2].ALLMEMBERS,
[Deal].[Agent].[Agent].ALLMEMBERS
)
```

Comment: (upped) this is a good idea @user1921849 you could add such a custom set into xl via it's built-in mdx tools.

Comment: going to be tricky to create the column `Participant Role` ? Would that be a custom member in the `WITH` clause?

Answer (score 0):

I would start with the following:

1. Download & install OLAP PivotTable Extensions from https://olappivottableextend.codeplex.com/
2. Open Excel and connect to your Cube
3. Build your query/report using drag and drop attributes.
4. Use plugin to copy the required MDX Query and edit as required.

Comment: a link to the (good) addin would have been sufficient in the comments section of the question: is this really an answer?

Comment: I think it is valid answer to someone who has limited MDX experience.